# How to Set Texture of a Plane to Second Camera Feed (Three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

In a three.js project I am working on, I need the texture of a cube to be the camera output of different users and positions in the scene. Think of it like this: *some users are holding cameras, and each of the cube's faces is a screen that is displaying one of the cameras output*. I have been stuck for a while on this part, and can not find any other cases of this online.

My first thought was to render each camera to a buffer canvas, get the `imagedata` from each of those buffer canvases, and use those as the textures for the cube. This was insanely slow, because I had to render each camera, get the `imagedata` of each buffer, convert that to a file that the texture loader could read, load it, and then finally set it. Not only was it slow, but it was also really ugly and I didn't want to keep spending more time on a solution that wasn't going to work (I'll leave the code out for now).

The only other way I can see this problem being solved it by creating a texture straight from a camera, without the use of the buffer, but I can not find any way of getting a camera's output.

So, is there a way to get a camera's output in three.js and if so, how to set a texture to that output?

Comment: Not sure how you implemented this, but i think the three.js build-in way to do this is a RenderTarget, an example here https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-rendertargets.html and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_rtt.html

Comment: I had seen something like this in OpenGL, but do I need to make a copy scene for each render target, or is there a way to make the render target part of the scene?

Comment: You can reuse same scene and same camera, or, use different scenes/cameras

Comment: Ok I was worried about the possibility of endless loops where the camera renders the screen that is being rendered by the camera that is rendering the screen.... would this fall into this trap?